# links in twitter bootstrap <ul <li not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to make a site using WrapBoootstrap and ive run into a problem, im trying to make it so that in the navbar next to the various buttons leading to anchor points there is a flag and if you press on it it will link to the other index.html page which is in Russian.

For some reason that doesnt work (it works only if you scrollwheel click it Aka Open it in a new tab). If i remove it from the navbar-list it works, but then it doesnt react when you make the page smaller and so on. I guess its some setting in the navbar that is not allowing links to be pressed

Im not very competent you might tell but help is much appreciated.

```html
<nav class="navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse collapse" role="navigation" style="height: 1px;">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right responsive-nav main-nav-list">

    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#aboutus">About Us & Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#works">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index2.html" target="_self">
      <img src="images/russian-flag-small.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: did you write lu instead of ul ?

Comment: Is it just a copy & paste error that in your last `<li>`, you didn't open an `a` tag? `<a href="indexRUS.html" target="_self">`

Comment: Yeah i dont know why the <a tag isnt there but its there in the document.

Comment: Well your code works for me (http://www.bootply.com/2enLa7486Y), the source of the problem must be somewhere else..

Comment: Yeah the HTML code alone is fine, i have no idea where the problem is though. How can i make it easier for you to troubleshoot?

Comment: Try to recreate your problem in jsfiddle or bootply (bootply already has bootstrap included, so it would be best for your current problem) by including most of your essential code (HTML and CSS).

Comment: I have no idea how i would recreate the problem. There are like 7 different .css files and a bunch of .js . 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> In the beginning of index.html. Can that be the source of the problem? I tried disabling all other .css and .js and that didnt fix the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem and the reason was the normalize/reset.css file

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>href="index2.html" target="_self">
```

You type it wrongly. It should be:

```
<li>
  <a href="index2.html" target="_self">
  <img src="images/russian-flag-small.jpg">
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: There was a copy paste error, i have <a tags in mine aswell. Sorry.